# How to convert string to time in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have data in table "2:00 PM-3:00 PM"
Here, I want to print start time based on AM PM.
For example print start time(2:00PM) as number 14:00.

Can you please suggest sql query for this.

Comment: Which DB you are using?

Comment: Your format time isn't standard, you can eventually convert it if you've got only one time in your data

Comment: MYSQL database version 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do it using [date_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php)

```
$date = new \DateTime('2:00PM');
echo date_format($date, 'H:i');

// Output: 14:00
```

But if you're getting this information from the DB you can do it on query-level but the way of doing it depends on which database you're using.

For example with mysql you can do it using [DATE_FORMAT()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp).

Comment: I want in sql query not in php